# Placing smaller rectangle with info icon inside horizontal rectangle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a horizontal rectangle as shown in attached image.[horizontal rectanglr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeRbS.png)

I am able to make horizontal rectangle with following css on my div

```
.Rectangle {
  width: 516px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(78, 158, 186, 0.2);
  background-color: #e5f1f5;
}

<div class="Rectangle "></div>
```

but I am not able to make small solid rectangle in left side of attached image with info icon. How can I make that small rectangle and place info icon in it?
CSS for smaller rectangle is as follows::

```
.Rectangle-14 {
  width: 60px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #4e9eba;
}
```

CSS for info icon is as follows::

```
.info-icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

How can I do that?

Here is the link of my fiddle  [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aman77/mrtx8fp2/1/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I have written working code sir. Don't know how to use jsFiddle in stackoverflow. If you know you can do it

Comment: Post also your relevant html code please

Comment: Sounds like a learning opportunity.

Comment: I just want to create exact same rectangle as mentioned in attached image. There is no extra code for it

Comment: If you simply apply my rectangle style on div you will get horizontal rectangle of blue color. But I am not getting smaller rectangle with icon

Comment: added fiddle as well

Comment: Well clearly there *should* be more code...what have you tried to make this work? **That's** what we need to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy with Flex. Consider learning that. A good resource can be : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

You can do it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/bhanusingh/kny0v2m1/5/

```css
.Rectangle {
  width: 516px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid 1px rgba(78, 158, 186, 0.2);
  background-color: #e5f1f5;
  display: flex;
  
}


.Rectangle .left_icon {
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #049fbb;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-right:10px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="Rectangle ">
  <div class="left_icon">
    <img src="https://imgplaceholder.com/25x25" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>This is an example text
</p>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi bhanu you there? I also wrote one code and facing one issue in it. could you please help?

Comment: I have one doubt similar to your solution. you there?

Comment: hey tell me, what's the doubt?

Comment: my doubt is  somewhat not related to this question. My doubt is how can represent width , height, border, padding as mentioned in above CSS in percentage instead of padding?

Comment: I got some examples online but I am very confused on how to calculate exact percentage for px

Comment: i guess that you are starting to learn CSS. This can be confusing at the start but its really simple. You should definetly check out this resource by w3school (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp). It will explain you how, box model works, once you get the grip of that consider understanding about the property `box-sizing` . This will be essential when you are working on a project where you have to implement the given design. i would also suggest going through all the w3school css content. Its a good resource. Also if my answered solved your problem, pls mark it as correct.